# How can I populate a form (or other element) based on option selected from a json generated select list?

Tags: jquery, json

I have a  list that is generated from JSON data. I would like to populate a form, or div, or really any element, using the option selected, and filling the element with the form data. I have parsed my JSON and can access it as needed, but I have no idea how to create the on page element I need and populate it with the data. I can do things like create lists, or tables, or list ALL of the json data on the page without issue, but I simply can't figure out how to select one of the options and have that populate an element with the expected data. I can't use a separate html page or anything easy because of how the data is being handled. I'll show as much code as I have below and hopefully a json and javascript expert can help me out as I'm sort of hitting a wall with my skills at this point.

I've created the select list dynamically and parsed the data into the page. You'll see some extra console loggingn going on as I've tested and tried a bunch of things to make this work. I'm thinking maybe something with key values or an if statement (like if value or ID equals something, show X data) but I'm stuck there too and need to be able to reproduce the same content creation over different iterations of this app by just changing the json file. Hopefully this makes sense because I feel like this can be done and isn't as hard as I'm making it but I can't find an answer anywhere for this issue.

#### Javascript getting the json and creating the list as well as populating the dropdown list

```
// Data Files
const dataFile = "./app/assets/data/schools.json";
const fileInput = fs.readFileSync(dataFile);
const result = JSON.parse(fileInput);

function setup() {
    loadJSON("/app/assets/data/schools.json", receivedData);
  }

  function receivedData(data) {
    console.log(data);
  }

$.each(result, function(i) { 
    var schools = result.schools;

    for (var i = 0; i < schools.length; i++) {
    console.log(schools[i].id + ' ' + schools[i].name + ' ' + schools[i].topic); 
    }
});

  $.each(result, function(i) {
    var schools = result.schools;
    var output = '';
    var menuDropdown = $("#schoolDropdown");
    console.log(schools);
    for (var i = 0; i < schools.length; i++) {
      output +=
        "<option value=" +
        schools[i].topic +
        ' ' +
        "id=" +
        schools[i].id +
        ' ' +
          "name=" +
          "dropDownItem" + 
          i +
          '">' +
        schools[i].name +
        "</option>";
      //     var word = keys[i];
      //     var score = data[word];
      //     var x = random(width);
      //     var y = random(height);
      //     fill(255);
      //     textSize(26);
      //     text(word, x, y)
    }
    menuDropdown.html(output);
  });


var dropDownTrigger = $("#schoolInfo")
dropDownTrigger.click(function(){
    var menuDropdown = $("#schoolDropdown");
    if (menuDropdown.hasClass("show")) {
        menuDropdown.removeClass("show")
    }
    else {
        menuDropdown.addClass("show");
    }
    // console.log("click event");

})
```

#### Simple HTML I want to fill the #App div with a form that generates content from the schools.json file based on the option selected

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="sidebar" style="margin-bottom:42px;">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="menuItem">
          <img
            src="/App/Assets/Images/lockout-logo-white.png"
            class="app-logo"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="menuItem active" id="main">
          Dashboard
        </div>
        <div style="display: flex;position:relative">
        <div class="menuItem school-dropdown" id="schoolInfo">
          School Information              
        </div>
        <select size="2" class="school-dropdown-list" id="schoolDropdown">
        </select>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container" id="App"></div>
```

#### Totally stuck

Sorry I can't give more info, I don't really even know where to go. The only thing I can find that pertains to this is filling another select list with elements based on my select dropdown. That isn't helpful. It could be a form, or maybe appending the #App div with html with the json data nested in there, anything that anyone has done similar to what I'm after would be super helpful.

#### What I think I want it to look like?

```
<div id="SCHOOL_ID_FROM_JSON">
    <div class="col-4">
    <h3>SCHOOL_NAME_FROM_JSON</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>ADDRESS_FROM_JSON</li>
        <li>PRINCIPAL_FROM_JSON</li>
        <li>PHONE_FROM_JSON</li>
    </ul>
    <select>
        <options filled with ZONES_FROM_JSON>
    </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-8">
        <img src="IMAGE_FROM_JSON based on zone selection />
    </div>
</div>
```

#### Maybe an onchange function to change the div?

I am thinking that an onchange function on the navigation select options could then generate the proper data to fill the #App div with the correct information. Sounds stupid but maybe a form in the background that fills with the data in inputs then fills the divs and lists with the right data in the #App container? Not sure. This video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aY2pVCDcE_c changes some image from static files, I need to have it be dynamic based on the json though.

Comment: You need to set attribute `selected="selected"` or just `selected` on option that need to be selected. You need to put `if` statement in the loop and the check for the correct value and in that `if` you put different option with selected

Comment: @jcubic would I be able to load the correct json data into the divs and lists this way? I feel like I can do certain things with your suggestion like if (CERTAIN_VALUE is selected) {
 Display a div
}
but would that make the actual data dynamic? Maybe I am just not seeing the application of your suggestion correctly. Would you mind elaborating a little?

Comment: @jcubic I feel like there is some way to match the ids or values from the select list and then use selected like you said to filter down through the elements and generate the content from the json file, I just don't know how.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, you have one select element, what you want to match? If you want to display value in div based on select you use `change` event get the value from select and update the element based on value.

Comment: @jcubic I think I may not have explained as well as I could have. I need to be able to dynamically insert json data into the div based on the option that is selected from the dropdown, which is also created by json. For example, if the school with index 0 is selected, I want the div to populate with all the other information from that same school, but dynamically similar to how the select list itself is populated. I just don't know how to match the selected option to the divs dynamically. I know there are ways to do it with a framework like react but that's not possible in this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, you store index in array in data attribute and get it on change:

```
// this will be slow if you select same element in loop,
// it's better to put it outside of the loop
var menuDropdown = $("#schoolDropdown");
var output = '';

// you had empty each because you don't access element of result
var schools = result.schools;
console.log(schools);
for (var i = 0; i < schools.length; i++) {
      output +=
        '<option value="' + schools[i].topic +
        '" data-index="' + i + '" ' +
        'id="' + schools[i].id + '" ' +
        'name="dropDownItem' + i + '">' +
        schools[i].name +
        "</option>";
  }
  // also better to have one DOM change.
  menuDropdown.html(output);

menuDropdown.change(function() {
    var value = menuDropdown.val();
    // get option based on value attribute
    var option = menuDropdown.find('option[value="' + value + '"]');
    var school = result.schools[option.data('index')];
    $('#description').html(school.description);
});
```

Comment: All I had to do was change 'name="dropDownItem' + + '">' to  'name="dropDownItem' + i + '">' and I don't have description in my data (I forgot to show it so you couldn't have known that!) hot dang it worked!!! Thank you so much I've been fighting with this for like two days trying to get it to work right!!! You just saved my butt, I'm accepting the answer now.